# Why A and B are equal after sort()?

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
function randOrd() {
    return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5)
}

A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
var B = A.sort(randOrd)
console.log('A=',A)
console.log('B=',B)
```

---

output:

```
a= [ 3, 4, 0, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7 ]
b= [ 3, 4, 0, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7 ]
```

I expected `a` to be the original array and `b` to be sorted. But they are both equal (sorted), why?

Comment: you miss a lot of semicolons

Comment: @mithunsatheesh semicolons are not mandatory in JavaScript

Comment: You can use `.slice()` to get a shallow clone of the `Array` -- `var B = A.slice(0).sort(randOrd);`

Comment: Workaround: `var B = A.slice().sort(randOrd)`

Comment: [Reading documentation usually helps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): "The `sort(`) method sorts the elements of an array *in place* and returns the array."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the Array.sort() method [sorts in-place and then returns the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript sort function sorts the array in place, meaning its modifying the original array and returning it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Because you're running the method 'sort' on var A... which firstly will sort A into an order, and then set that data to B... which is why you get identical answers for A and B